# Can ssh to EC2 instance but can't eb ssh

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

When I try to SSH to a certain one of my EC2 instances, it works fine:

```
ssh -i "jason.pem" ec2-user@ec2-34-222-8-173.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
# the above works
```

When I try to do `eb ssh` it doesn't work. Strangely, it worked for months before today, but now it's not working, even though I can't imagine that anything has changed. Here's the failure:

```
INFO: Attempting to open port 22.
INFO: SSH port 22 open.
INFO: Running ssh -i /Users/jasonswett/.ssh/jason.pem ec2-user@34.222.8.173
ec2-user@34.222.8.173: Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: An error occurred while running: ssh.
```

How can I troubleshoot this?

**Edit:**

I've isolated the problem to a certain degree.

This works:

```
ssh -i 'jason.pem' ec2-user@34.222.8.173
```

but this doesn't:

```
ssh -i /Users/jasonswett/.ssh/jason.pem ec2-user@34.222.8.173
```

So obviously, the difference is the value of what's passed for the `-i` flag. Unfortunately it's the second, non-working command that `eb ssh` currently uses.

What I still don't understand yet is why this makes a difference or what I can do to fix the issue.

**Edit 2:**

Per @KJH's advice I tried running each of the above commands with the `-v` flag.

This is the output for the `'jason.pem'` version:

```
ssh -i 'jason.pem' ec2-user@34.222.8.173 -v                                
Warning: Identity file jason.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.                        
OpenSSH_7.8p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018                                                         
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config                               
debug1: Connecting to 34.222.8.173 [34.222.8.173] port 22.                                     
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/jasonswett/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
```

So, surprisingly, the reason that that command works is because the specified identify file doesn't exist. Evidently it's falling back to the default, `/Users/jasonswett/.ssh/id_rsa`, which does exist.

So apparently somewhere my EB CLI config is saying "use `/Users/jasonswett/.ssh/jason.pem` for the identity file when `eb ssh` is run" and I have to change it to either specify `/Users/jasonswett/.ssh/id_rsa` or not specify anything. So far I haven't been able to find where that configuration directive is set though.

Comment: By the way, if it helps, I did a ping and it looks like `ec2-34-222-8-173.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` does in fact resolve to `34.222.8.173`. I wanted to check that to see if it was a case of `eb ssh` trying to connect to the wrong EC2 instance.

Comment: Also if it helps, `ssh -i "jason.pem" ec2-user@34.222.8.173` works fine.

Comment: Throw in the `-v` flag to see if it gives you any additional useful info.

Comment: @KJH Thanks. That did give me some useful info and I updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't imagine this is the only possible solution but I was able to resolve my issue by running `eb ssh --setup` and generating a new keypair. Now a bare `eb ssh` command works fine.

Comment: worked for me as well